# Am I understanding the proficiency system correctly?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, proficiency

My DM is a DM that mainly cares about making sure we are understanding the game and having fun, so he let me be a griffin. I'm a level 2 wizard and level 2 thief.

The DM says at my level I should have 6 proficiency points to spend. I have Takeoff and Landing proficiencies, and the DM said to add three points to Landing and 3 points to Takeoff. So, I spent 6 points. But he also said I get to add 1 point to grappling.

I am confused. I had six points to spend, but it seems I spent 7. Can you help me understand, or am I being a mindless zombie again?

Comment: *"**my Question is** that i have Takeoff and landing proficiencies and he said add three points to landing and 3 points to takeoff so i spent 6 points put i'm at level 2 Wizard and level 2 thief but at my level he said i should have 6 proficiency points to spend but he also said..."* — where the question was?

Comment: I've re-worded the original question to make more sense, while retaining the original words and hopefully the original meaning.

Comment: Are  you sure you're playing Dungeons & Dragons 5th edition?

Comment: I don't think we can reopen this until OP confirms that this is their actual question and that the game tagh is correct.

Answer (score 12):

#### Ask your DM

Unfortunately, you're describing rules that don't resemble the normal D&D 5th edition rules. This suggests that either your DM is using some non-standard rules, in which case you'll need to ask him, or that you haven't fully understood the standard game rules, in which case I recommend reading the [Player's Basic Rules](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules), then asking your DM for help building your character.

In particular, I suspect you're confusing *proficiency bonus*, which is a number you add to d20 rolls (at your level, this bonus is +3) and *proficiencies*, which is a list of things your character is proficient in and can apply that bonus to. You may quite plausibly have six skill proficiencies, depending on how your character is built and what your DM's custom griffin race gives.

Additionally, your character may indeeed have +1 bonus to grappling without actually acquiring any proficiency in that field. That would come from Strength, if your character has a Strength score of either 12 or 13.

Again, you would benefit from reading the [Player's Basic Rules](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules) between game sessions to understand the core rules of the game, as the number and complexity of Dungeons & Dragons rules can be overwhelming for new players at first.